# Booting Windows from different partition than system

Tags: windows, ssd, grub, bootloader

I have bought an SSD disk, but my laptop (Dell Precision M6300) refuse to use it as a target disk for windows (AHCI on/off, BIOS up-to-date).

----**EDIT**----

I tried with Windows 7 and 8 - same results. During the regular installation from CD or USB, when I should choose the destination disk, installer yields that selected disk will probably not boot. It suggests to change BIOS settings to turn it on, Google says to turn on AHCI or upgrade BIOS. Checked, still the same.

----**END EDIT**---

I can't exchange the disk unfortunately... But fortunately, I've managed to install windows using USB disk case. The problem is, that when I put that disk as my internal drive it can't boot. (Disk read error, Three Finger Salute ...)

So I tried with Linux (openSUSE), I manage to install it as well, but when I tried to boot GRUB from internal drive I get errors again. (Should I try GRUB2?)

I figured out that I can boot into that internal hard drive's openSUSE system using small USB drive with GRUB, kernel and image on it. So, I just run GRUB from USB drive, it loads necessary stuff **from the USB drive** and then continues from the internal drive.

I want to do the same with Windows. But GRUB (`rootnoverify` and `chainloader +1`) does not boot my windows on internal drive.

The question: is there any chance to copy the critical windows' boot files into the USB drive, to make it possible to boot from that USB drive, but continue booting from internal (different in general) drive? The USB drive would became a system hardware key! ;-)

Disk: Plextor M5S 128GB Sata III, laptop has Sata II, but it's compatible anyway, right?

Comment: Which version of Windows, and what I can't understand is, why couldn't you install it on your new SSD? What errors did you get? Why not post a question regarding that first and try and fix it, instead of looking for workarounds/hacks?

Comment: I think, Windows version is not important. The solution for the very first problem is to change laptop or disk. But it's not an option before X-mas. Question Edited...

Comment: there is a program that puts a boot manager on cd and then loads an OS off a usb stick , which is useful when a computer won't let you boot from usb.  so i guess it could load an OS from a hard drive. It's called plop boot manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to install Windows on that drive!

I have upgraded the disk's firmware. The newest version appeared on 14.12.2012, so it is very fresh. This is the first thing.

Second is a partition table. 
At first Windows claimed that disk is OK to boot, but partition is not. So, I've again used openSUSE to install it with grub. It worked fine with extra 50MB partition for grub, boot, kernel and image, so I tried with Windows. And it went well!

Windows asked me if I want another extra 300MB partition for some system stuff, I chose 'yes' and all went good.

So now my Windows 8 boot up in less than 10 seconds :) And I learnt my Windows 8 key by heart... :)

Best Regards!